# is our sadaqa accepted if we gave our sadaqa to professional beggers?

Tags: practical-islam, sadaqah

we live in a society where we have some time no idea about actually needy people and gave our sadaqa to some time professionl beggers as my concern I gave them my sadaqa to any begger because of reminding   the quote of HAZRAT imam HUSSAIN(A.S) comes in my mind that

"the needy ones lose their respect by asking you so do not lose your self respect by denying them"
so some time it really confuse me that em i doing right or wrong

Comment: What is a professional beggar?

Comment: the people who are not eligible for sadqa specially we see them on roads many of them are actually not the nedy one they do it as their profession and gave money to their leader who heired them but we dont have idea about them

Answer (score 1):

The ansewer of this is in the Quran. Some people say that you should never give money to beggars on the road, as they will buy drugs, alcohol or they are rich and don't need it. They may well buy alcohol or drugs but this is not your sin, this is their sin.  You are giving them money because they have said they are hungry, have no money for the bus for example, etc... Your intentions are good, you are doing a good deed. In the Quran it says many times "no barer of burden can bare the burden of another". Thus their sin is  their sin and your good deed is your good deed, you will not be held account for the sins they do. They Quran mentions a long list of people that you should give charity and this includes "those who ask".

But the Quran also mentions that you should try to get your charity to those most in need, so that it does not merely circulate among the rich,

Answer (score 0):

Whats matter is your intention, as long as you don't know that the receiver is professional beggar.

Comment: Not true. You can't have the intention of praying your daily prayer but then knowingly pray in the wrong direction. He knows the person is not poor. Rather its their profession